# Как изменить размер экрана?

Tags: android

Приставка к телевизору на Андроид имеет родное разрешение 1280 X 672. Она подключается к монитору или телевизору с соотношением 4:3. Приходится "сжимать" экран в настройках. Но тогда сверху и снизу остаются черные полосы. Если теперь на этом экране показывать видео с соотношением 3:4, то полосы остаются также слева и справа.

То есть несмотря на то, что соотношения сторон у видео и дисплея одинаковые оно показывается в центре, окруженное полосами.

Как сделать так, чтобы приложение было развернуто на этом мониторе на весь экран, но не растягивалось(в том числе текст, кнопки и т.д.), а показывалось нормально?

Comment: Не сжимайте экран в настройках, наверняка нельзя увеличить экран для конкретного приложения, тем более для конкретного видео.

Comment: Как тогда изменить соотношения сторон для кнопок и текста, чтобы они на растянутом дисплее смотрелись нормально? Видео и изображения можно просто сжимать по вертикали...

Answer (score 2):

А нельзя в настройки приложения вывести пункт по переключению в режим 4:3, а под этот режим сверстать другой фрагмент (см android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Comment: Можно и так. Можно переключение в пункт меню вынести, можно даже автоматически определять размер экрана, это хитрее, конечно, но можно. Можно верстать другой фрагмент, можно верстать другую активити... Проблема состоит в том, что даже при показываемом соотношении сторон 3:4 разрешение все равно будет 1280x672. И тогда все элементы выглядят вытянутыми по вертикали. Можно ли сжать все элементы интерфейса только по высоте, в том числе шрифты?